# How to extract two folder path C: (same Type File: e.g Text Document) and name of the file into text file with the file size in kb

Tags: vbscript

I have edited my provided VBscript but I could not generate the results. I need to extract two folder path C: (same Type File: e.g Text Document/Microsoft excel 2003) and name (e.g. AB01,DE02) of the file into text file with the file size in kb. When I run my VBscript, it shows

> Line:16, Char:29, Error: Expected’)’

Below is the script:

```
Sub Tester()

    Dim ObjOutFile

    Set ObjOutFile = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject"). _
    CreateTextFile("C:\Users\User\Desktop\outcome.txt")


    ListFiles ObjOutFile, "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Folder A", "Microsoft Office Word 97 - 2003 Document"

    ListFiles ObjOutFile, "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Folder A", "Microsoft Office Word 97 - 2003 Document"


    ObjOutFile.Close

End Sub


Sub ListFiles(f, folderPath, fileType)
    Dim ObjFiles, ObjFile, sz

    fileType = UCase(fileType)
    Set ObjFiles = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") _
    .getfolder(folderPath).Files

    For Each ObjFile In ObjFiles
        If UCase(ObjFile.Type) = fileType Then
            sz = Round(ObjFile.Size / 1024, 2)
            f.WriteLine sz & String(50 - Len(sz), " ") & ObjFile.Path
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

The error you observe is caused by the signature of your procedure `ListFiles`. In VBScript all variables/parameters are of type `Variant`, so you must not explicitly specify a type. Change this:

```
Sub ListFiles(f, folderPath As String, fileType As String)
```

into this:

```
Sub ListFiles(f, folderPath, fileType)
```

Comment: Hi Ansgar, thanks for your suggestion. I tried to execute with your script but i still cannot find the result. There is no error message pop out once i execute. I have edited my script as a testing purpose above. please have a look and kindly help me out.

Comment: Is what you posted your entire script? In that case add a line `Tester` at the end of the file. Otherwise the procedure would never be called and thus nothing would be executed.

Comment: Yes this is my entire script.I will run this script and let you know the outcome. Thanks a lot.